# howto read a stacktrace from c# like my example?

Tags: c#, stack-trace

how to read this stacktrace?
who can explain me how to understand this to fix the bug.

```
"Frame    Image             Function                                                             Offset    
0        coredll.dll       xxx_RaiseException                                                   19        
1        mscoree3_7.dll                                                                         436488    
2        mscoree3_7.dll                                                                         386545    
3        mscoree3_7.dll                                                                         540936    
4                          TransitionStub                                                       0         
5                          GeoCaching.Main.btnGoToPin_Click                                     312       
6                          System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick                132       
7                          System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick                               120       
8                          System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp    228       
9                          System.Windows.Controls.Control.OnMouseLeftButtonUp                  100       
10                         MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent                                     896       
11       mscoree3_7.dll                                                                         429164    
12       mscoree3_7.dll                                                                         430528    
13       mscoree3_7.dll                                                                         610803    
14       mscoree3_7.dll                                                                         374593    
15                                                                                              0         
16       agcore.dll        CCoreServices::CLR_FireEvent                                         385       
17       npctrl.dll        CControlBase::ScriptCallback                                         435       
18       npctrl.dll        CXcpDispatcher::OnScriptCallback                                     547       
19       npctrl.dll        CXcpDispatcher::OnReentrancyProtectedWindowMessage                   479"
```

Comment: Can't you show us a bit of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get much information from that stack trace. You can read the `Image` name, which is the name of the assembly where the methods are, and the `Function` name, which is the name of the method.

It looks like there was an exception in the `GeoCaching.Main.btnGoToPin_Click` or `TransitionStub` methods, but the stack trace alone doesn't tell you what kind of exception, or what information was put in the Exception object.

If you would have compiled the application with debug information on, you would get some more information in the stack trace, like the line number in each method.

Answer (score 0):

From the information provided can sal only that you got an exception inside `btnGoToPin_Click` .

To see the real source of that add a `try/catch`    inside that event handler and most probabbly you will find out the error.

Good luck

Comment: No, `312` is not a line number, it's an offset in the native code.

Answer (score 0):

As said before, the error is somewhere in the btnGoToPin_Click
**BUT** the application is compiled in Release mode, it's why you don't have the complete stacktrace.

When an app is compiled in release mode, the compiler make several optimisations.
The first one that could apply to your case is to replace call to small method by the body of this method. This is called "inlining optimisation"

So maybe your error is in another method called in btnGoToPin_Click but not visible to the stack trace due to inlining.

If you want more informations about inlining here is a [nice article](http://www.ademiller.com/blogs/tech/2008/08/c-inline-methods-and-optimization/)